# How to identify wikipedia categories in python

Tags: python, mediawiki, pywikibot

I am currently using `pywikibot` to obtain the categories of a given wikipedia page (e.g., `support-vector machine`) as follows.

```
import pywikibot as pw

print([i.title() for i in list(pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'support-vector machine').categories())])
```

The results I get is:

```
[
  'Category:All articles with specifically marked weasel-worded phrases',
  'Category:All articles with unsourced statements',
  'Category:Articles with specifically marked weasel-worded phrases from May 2018',
  'Category:Articles with unsourced statements from June 2013',
  'Category:Articles with unsourced statements from March 2017',
  'Category:Articles with unsourced statements from March 2018',
  'Category:CS1 maint: Uses editors parameter',
  'Category:Classification algorithms',
  'Category:Statistical classification',
  'Category:Support vector machines',
  'Category:Wikipedia articles needing clarification from November 2017',
  'Category:Wikipedia articles with BNF identifiers',
  'Category:Wikipedia articles with GND identifiers',
  'Category:Wikipedia articles with LCCN identifiers'
]
```

As you can see the results I am getting include lot of tracking and maintenance categories of wikipedia such as;

- Category:All articles with specifically marked weasel-worded phrases
- Category:All articles with unsourced statements
- Category:CS1 maint: Uses editors parameter
- etc.

However, the categories I am only interested are;

- Category:Classification algorithms
- Category:Statistical classification
- Category:Support vector machines

I am wondering if there is a way to get all `tracing or maintenance` wikipedia categories, so that I can remove them from the results to get only the informative categories.

Or, please suggest me if there are any other ways of eliminating them from the results.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Are `tracing` and `maintenance` artifacts of the actual library you are using, or your own terminology? If the library doesn't provide further identification of categories, you could simply filter based on known keywords in a list comprehension. E.g. `[cat for cat in categories if not any(exclude_keyword in cat for exclude_keyword in ['disputed', 'maintenance', ...])]`

Comment: @jpriebe thanks a lot for the comment. Actually `tracking` and `maintenance` are words I took from wikipedia (Look at this link of wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:CS1_maint:_Uses_editors_parameter). It seems like wikipedia have categorised the category links of them as `tracking/maintenance`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pywikibot` currently does not provide some of the [API features](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categories) for filtering hidden categories. You can do that manually by searching for the `hidden` key in `categoryinfo`:

```
import pywikibot as pw

site = pw.Site('en', 'wikipedia')
print([
    cat.title()
    for cat in pw.Page(site, 'support-vector machine').categories()
    if 'hidden' not in cat.categoryinfo
])
```

gives:

```
['Category:Classification algorithms', 
 'Category:Statistical classification', 
 'Category:Support vector machines']
```

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories#Hidden_categories and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Categorization#Hiding_categories for more info.